# Registry Lookup

Tags: group-policy, windows-registry

Is anyone on here familiar with a website that offers the ability to lookup specific registry/GPO settings such as `AutoAdminLogon`.  I imagine this site would give you the full path to the GPO setting and information about the option itself.

Comment: Google doesn't work well enough for you...?

Comment: @HopelessN00b Sure for a good chunk of these you can find searching around on Google, but don't you agree it would be nice if all this information were to be in one place?? I just wanted to know if there is a site out there which people are using that IS in one place.  There are times when you come across one which is difficult if not impossible to find accurate information for.

Answer (score 1):

http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net is the best, most modern thing there is.